# If A and B are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, with A$\subset$B, prove that infB$\leq$infA$\leq$supA$\leq$supB

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have the proof done I think, I just want to make sure it is correct.

Let $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$. Thus if $x \in A$, $x\in B$.

Assume there is $\alpha \in A$ such that $\alpha = supA$, therefore $\alpha > x$. Thus $\alpha \in B$ and so $x$ is not $supB$. If $supB$ is not $\alpha$, then $supB > \alpha$, so $supB \geq \alpha$, thus $supB \geq supA$.

Assume there is $\beta \in A$ such that $\beta = infA$, therefore $\beta < x$. Thus $\beta \in B$ and so $x$ is not $infB$. If $supB$ is not $\alpha$, then $infB > \beta$, so $infB \leq \beta$, thus $infB \leq infA$.

Thus $infB \leq infA \leq supA \leq supB$

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can say $\inf B$ is the minimum of $\inf A$ and $\inf B\setminus A$. Since the second may be smaller that the first, we have $\inf B\leq \inf A$. For the same reason $\sup B\geq\sup A$. It remains to prove that 
$\inf A\leq \sup A$, which is obvious.

Comment: $A \subset B$, so $infA$ should be $\geq infB$ not $\inf A\leq \inf B$

Comment: I corrected. I meant  $\inf A\leq \sup A$.